# I'm trying to make a wifi adapter with a old chipset

Tags: linux, wifi, compatibility

I want to know if a Ralink RT3070L chip has packet injection, monitor mode, and is compatible with Linux.

Comment: yes, probably, and yes.  it probably depends on exactly which card you've got, since even different cards with the same chipset can sometimes behave differently

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you identified the chip correctly, it looks like the answers are: **yes**, it should work with the `rt2800usb` driver included in the standard kernels, **but no**, it seems to have no monitor mode or any such advanced functionality. It looks like it can function either as a regular WiFi host adapter or as an Access Point, and maybe in AdHoc or mesh modes, but that's it.

It seems to support only one mode at a time, so if you need to act as an AP and simultaneously have an uplink to a real AP, you'll need *two* RT3070L's for that.

I searched for NL80211_IFTYPE_* constants, and the entire `rt2x00` driver family does not have even a single reference to NL80211_IFTYPE_MONITOR, which would be used to indicate monitor mode capability.

Ralink used to provide an externally-maintained driver, but since the chipset is so old and Ralink was acquired by MediaTek, any version of that driver you can find is probably intended for ancient kernel versions and no longer maintained.